# Averaging predictions with different training sets

Tags: svm, random-forest, prediction, ensemble-learning

I've taken a stacking approach to building an ensemble model for classification. The final model is a random forest using results from neural network, svm, and k-nearest neighbor models. The results are very sensitive to the initial data partitioning procedure. The area under the ROC curve ranges from 0.59 to 0.98 depending upon which data are used as training and testing. My question: Can I run 100 iterations in which the data are partitioned differently and then average the results for each record across those 100 iterations? Is this a legit means of accounting for the variation of results caused by different data partitions?